# Changing NSMutableArray size in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, size

I was looking around and couldn't find anything, and I'm starting to think it's not possible with objective-c.

I have a `NSMutableArray *myMutableArray` and the size varies depending on what csv file is loaded. Since I do not set a size of `myMutableArray` I can't do:

```
       if (c == 5){

          myMutableArray[q] = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myOtherArray] stringValue];

          q = q + 1;
          c = 0;
       }

       Else {

           c = c + 1; 

       }
```

Since `myMutableArray` is technically of size `nil` I guess I can't add objects to it.

In cases, `q` can be between 1500 and 2500.

My question is, how do I make `myMutableArray' change size on every loop.

If this isn't possible, I guess I will have to make `myMutableArray` very large - but I need the values in `myMutableArray` for a graph. If I do `myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5000];` and don't use the 5000 memory locations, will these locations be nil, or 0? (sorry if the technical words are wrong, by memory locations I mean the memory given to `myMutableArray`)

Thank you, if there is anything else I can add to this please feel free to let me know.

EDIT: What I'm trying to achieve is adding data to the array, and with that data create a graph

Comment: you better explain what exactly you need to achieve cause obviously you're going to do a wrong thing

Comment: and one more - Since myMutableArray is technically of size nil - it cannot be of size nil

Comment: @AndreyChernukha edited OP for what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: if you want just add objects to the array so what's wrong with simply using addObject: method?

Comment: Can I do that even if I don't set the array size?

Comment: how about just letting the array do what it does best and just initialise it whit [NSMutableArray new] and just use it like that if  you don't need to know the exact index of the objects in the array use     addObject: method. EDIT: if the array is mutable it automatically changes its capacity when adding objects. IF you need to know the exact index of the values you store i would go with Wain's answer.

Comment: all you need is to initialize your array with [NSMutableArray new] and that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **NSMutableArray** class declares the programmatic interface to objects that manage a modifiable array of objects. This class adds insertion and deletion operations to the basic array-handling behavior inherited from **NSArray.**

If you 
arrayWithCapacity:
Creates and returns an NSMutableArray object with enough allocated memory to initially hold a given number of objects.

Mutable arrays expand as needed. When declaring them, we can init them like this:

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems
```

Here numItems simply establishes the object’s initial capacity.

Later to add more data, i.e. to expand mutable array, use this

```
addObject:
```

What it does is, it inserts a given object at the end of the mutable array.

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject
```

**It's important to note that:**
The object to add to the end of the array's content. This value must not be nil. It raises an **NSInvalidArgumentException** if anObject is nil.

Comment: `arrayWithCapacity:` does not always allocate enough memory to hold the specified number of objects.  That is used merely as a hint to configure the array.  Since arrays can't have holes (empty slots), there is no need to consume all of said memory.

Comment: @bbum sorry but apple documentation for NSMutableArray class reference says otherwise. :(

Comment: Nope;  the docs simply state *establishes the initial capacity* not that the array has allocated memory to hold all of that capacity.  Array's backing store are not linearly allocated chunks of memory and the details change with the size of the array.  This may be illuminating:  http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a sporadically populated array. Creating an array with `capacity` 5000 is just a hint as to how much data you might be going to store into the array. Consider using an array of dictionaries where the dictionary contains the `q` value (presumably one coordinate) and the associated value. You can then sort the array based on the `q` values if you need to (for plotting). Then you can just add the dictionaries to the array as usual (`addObject:`).